# Validating captcha along with passport.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, recaptcha

Is it possible to verify if google recaptcha succeeded before calling passport.js authenticate function?

I'm getting stuck between choosing one or the other because both use asynchronous callbacks to verify and I can't next them within each other.

```
    function verifyRecaptcha(key, rq, rs, pa, callback) {
    https.get('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' + SECRET + '&response=' + key, function (res) {
        var data = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data += chunk.toString();
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            try {
                var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
//                    return true;
                callback(parsedData.success, rq, rs, pa);
            } catch (e) {
//                    return false;
                callback(false, rq, rs, pa);
            }
        });
    });
}

    app.post('/auth/signin', can_access.if_not_logged_in(), passport.setupLocalStrategy(),
    function (req, res) {
        console.log('HERE');

        verifyRecaptcha(req.body['g-recaptcha-response'], function (success) {
            if (success) {
                // find a way to signal captcha succeeded.
                return true;
            } else {
                res.end('Captcha failed, sorry.');
                // TODO: take them back to the previous page
                // and for the love of everyone, restore their inputs
                return false;
            }
        });
    },
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: 'auth/signin',
        failureFlash: true
    }));
```

I want to do authentication after captcha has succeeded

Comment: Can you show your existing code where you're stuck with not being able to call both async callbacks?

Comment: I added the code where I am stuck. I want to first detect that the captcha succeeded, then if it did it would return true which would allow the post method to move to check the authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way Express middlewares or route handlers work is that they are executed in succession, one after another, as long as the previous one called `next()`

So you just need to call `next()` from your captcha verifying middleware so that your `passport.authenticate` middleware which comes next can be executed.

Also, if you call `next(err)` (i.e. passing it an Error) it will skip all the middlewares and go straight to the next middleware that has the 4 argument signature `(err, req, res, next)`, which is usually the main error handler placed at or near the end in your routes/middlewares.

So simply try changing your code to this:

```
app.post('/auth/signin', can_access.if_not_logged_in(), passport.setupLocalStrategy(),
function (req, res, next) { // <<-- 1. have next passed here
    console.log('HERE');

    verifyRecaptcha(req.body['g-recaptcha-response'], function (success) {
        if (success) {
            // find a way to signal captcha succeeded.
            return next(); // <<-- 2. call next(); 
        } else {
            res.end('Captcha failed, sorry.');
            // TODO: take them back to the previous page
            // and for the love of everyone, restore their inputs
            return false;
        }
    });
},
// this will only be invoked if next() was called from previous middleware 
passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: 'auth/signin',
    failureFlash: true
}));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked. I had no idea thats what the next function was for.